# Elasticsearch remote access through SSH

Tags: ssh, elasticsearch

About Elasticsearch HTTP API, I wonder if I want to remote access a cluster on SSH server,
what should I include in my http rest command:

```
    curl -XGET ' http://localhost:9200/ index /_mapping/ type '
```

I have tried something like below but got failed:

```
    curl -XGET -u cloud-user: --key ~/.ssh/id_rsa --pubkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub  'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200/index/_mapping/type'
```

Is there anyone knows the correct command or alternative solution?

Comment: Create a port tunnel with putty: http://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/windows/ssh-port-tunneling-with-putty/

Answer (score 10):

If you are on *NIX environment it is easy, just tunnel over ssh

```
ssh -Nf -L 9200:localhost:9200 user@remoteserver.com
```

Later you fetch the remote by localhost, as tunneled above

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_search'
```

Comment: Is it also possible to write changes via this type of connection? is it a different story?