# ssh tunnel for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am on a vpn which does not allow access to elasticsearch directly, so I am trying to ssh tunnel to an external box that has access.

I am tunneling with the following:

```
ssh -L 12345:<elastic_ip>-east-1.aws.found.io:9200
```

but then if I curl:

```
curl http://user:pass@localhost:12345
```

I get:

```
{"ok":false,"message":"Unknown cluster."}
```

Yet, if I try this from the box directly:

```
curl http://user:pass@<elastic_ip>-east-1.aws.found.io:9200
```

I get:

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "instance",
  "cluster_name" : “<cluster>”,
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.7.2",
    "build_hash" : “<build>“,
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-09-14T09:49:53Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I could be wrong, but it may use the port number as a form of identification - just for testing purposes, can you try using `ssh -L 9200:<ip>:9200` and then `curl localhost:9200`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25048045/elasticsearch-remote-access-through-ssh

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it using #SSH tunneling with #Putty.

Below are the steps you need to take in order to configure SSH tunneling using Putty:

- Download Putty from [here](https://medium.com/r/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chiark.greenend.org.uk%2F~sgtatham%2Fputty%2Fdownload.html) and install it.
- Configure Putty tunneling for Elasticsearch 9300 and 9200 ports as shown in the screenshot below:
  [image]
- After configuring you’ll need to open the SSH connection and make sure it is connected.
- You may look at the SSH event log in order to validate your tunnel. [Here](https://medium.com/r/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D7YNd1tFJfwc) is a link on how to do it.

Below is an #Elasticsearch code written in #Java that shows how to connect to the remote Elasticsearch cluster using local (9090 and 9093) ports forwarded over Putty SSH client.

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().
             put("cluster.name", "my-cluster").build();

        TransportClient client = new TransportClient(settings)
                                 .addTransportAddress(
                                  new netSocketTransportAddress(
                                  "localhost", 9093));

        CreateIndexResponse rs = client.admin().indices().create(
                      new CreateIndexRequest("tunnelingindex"))
                     .actionGet();

        System.out.println(rs.isAcknowledged());
        client.close();
    }
}
```

The code creates an index named tunnelingindex on Elasticsearch.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Works fine with Kaizen (ES GUI client). But if your ES server accessible from destination SSH server only then you must provide `127.0.0.1:9200` as  `Destination`

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of HTTP protocol. It contains also hostnames and not only IP addresses and if you issue request on the `localhost`, this hostname is passed to the cluster.

There are basically two solutions, both quite hacky:

1. Set up your elasticsearch hostname to `localhost` so it will recognize your query.
2. Set up your `/etc/hosts` to direct `<elastic_ip>-east-1.aws.found.io` to your `127.0.0.1`, connect to your `ssh` with direct IP and then `curl` to the real address.